# Is the pronoun "which" used correctly in the second instance in this text?

Tags: relative-pronouns

Taking into account the location of every word in the next piece of text, I find the use of the word "which" confusing as it is intended to allude to the spinal nerves and not to the sympathetic nervous system.

spinal nerve n : any of the paired nerves which leave the spinal cord of a craniate vertebrate, supply muscles of the trunk and limbs, and connect with the nerves of the sympathetic nervous system, which arise by a short motor ventral root and a short sensory dorsal root, and of which there are 31 pairs in humans classified according to the part of the spinal cord from which they arise into 8 pairs of cervical nerves, 12 pairs of thoracic nerves, 5 pairs of lumbar nerves, 5 pairs of sacral nerves, and one pair of coccygeal nerves

Comment: The relative pronoun "which" occurs four times in that paragraph. Which instances of it are you referring to?

Comment: I am talking about the second instance

Answer (score 1):

That second *which* can't refer to *sympathetic nervous system* because the following verb, *arise*, requires a plural subject. But it could refer to *nerves of the sympathetic nervous system* or to *any of the paired nerves*, so it's ambiguous.

The sentence really should be broken into two or more sentences.

Comment: Thank you! As this is a learners text, I find this unbelievable!